# Java: Reading from a text file && Check whether the graph is complete or not

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a school assignment that I finished most of, but I can't figure out how to read from a text file, and I'm having a certain problem regarding the code, The task I was given is:

> "Write a program to read an input file named “input.txt”. The file
> consists of several graphs. Each graph starts with a line containing
> the number of vertices n, where 1 < n < 200. Each vertex is labeled by
> a number from 0 to n-1. The second line contains the number of edges
> l. After this, l lines follow each containing two vertex numbers
> representing an edge. An input with n = 0 marks the end of the input
> and is not to be processed.
>
> You have to choose an appropriate data structure to represent the
> graph. Indicate whether its Complete/has a self loop/ has an isolated
> vertex "
> Sample Input:
>
> 4
>
> 5
>
> 0 1
>
> 2 0
>
> 0 3
>
> 1 2
>
> 2 3
>
> 3
>
> 3
>
> 0 1
>
> 1 2
>
> 2 0
>
> 0
>
> Sample output:
>
> Not Complete/No Self-Loop/No Isolated Vertex
>
> Complete/No Self-Loop/No Isolated Vertex

I used adjacency matrix, I wrote code that reads the edges, decided whether it has a self loop and whether there's an isolated vertex.

1- I wrote a code for finding whether it's complete or not, but it doesn't behave the way I want it, it always shows that It's not complete.

2- I am not familiar with the way to read inputs from a text file, so please I need help.

The part where I have to make it read any amount of matrices, is kinda easy (but leaving a hint for it is always welcomed hehe), but I just wanna make sure I know how to do the two steps above before I do it, I'd really appreciate leaving comments so I could learn whatever step you help me with, anyway, this is the program:

```
package phase1project;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Phase1Project {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    int max = 2000; //declare the max element for the array
    int[][] adj= new int[max][max]; //declare the array
    int n; //nodes
    int l; // to determine the max number of edges
    int loopChecker = 0;//To check whether there's a loop or not
    int isolatedCounter = 0;
    int completeCounter = 0;
    int subCounter = 0;
    int origin; //to determine where the edge starts
    int destination; //to detemine where the edge stops
    
    int i,j; //for the loop
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); //to scan inputs
            
    System.out.println("Enter the number of vertices: ");
    n=input.nextInt();
    while(n<1 || n>200){ //nodes/vertices should be between 1 and 200
        System.out.println("\nWrong input! Insert a numbe between 1 and 200\n");
        n=input.nextInt();
    }
    
    System.out.println("Enter the number of edges: ");
    l=input.nextInt();
    
    System.out.println("Enter the begining of the edge then press enter then enter the end side of the edge to input it correctly.\n");
    
    for(i=0;i<=(l-1);i++){ //a loop that populates the adjacency matrix
            
        System.out.println("Enter edge "+i+": >> (0 0) to quit: ");
        origin = input.nextInt();
        destination = input.nextInt();
        
            adj[origin][destination]=1;
    }
    
    System.out.println("\n\n\nThis is how your graph looks like:\n");
    
    for(i=0;i<=(n-1);i++){
        for(j=0;j<=(n-1);j++)
            System.out.printf("%4d",adj[i][j]);
        System.out.printf("\n");
    }
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //Loop Checker starts from here
    for(i=0;i<=(n-1);i++){
        if(adj[i][i]==1){//If there's a 1 in the same place
            loopChecker=1;
            break;   
        }
    }
    
    if(loopChecker==1){
        System.out.println("Self Loop");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("No Self Loop");
    }
    //Loop Checker ends here

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //checks whether the graph is complete
    for(i=0;i<=(n-1);i++){
        subCounter=0;//reset
        for(j=0;j<=(n-1);j++){
            if(adj[i][j]==1){
                subCounter+=1;//buffer variable
            }
            if(subCounter==(n-1)){
                completeCounter+=1;//this counter incriments if the whole line has 1s that equal n-1
            }  
        }
        
    }
    
    if(completeCounter == n){
        System.out.println("Complete");
    }
    else
        System.out.println("Not Complete");
    //end of complete or not check
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    
    
    subCounter =0;//reset
    //checks whether the graph has an isolated vertex or not
    for(i=0;i<=(n-1);i++){
        for(j=0;j<=(n-1);j++){
            if(adj[i][j]==0){
                subCounter+=1;//buffer variable
            }
            if(subCounter==n){
                isolatedCounter=1;
                break;
            }  
        }
        subCounter=0;//reset
    }
    
    if(isolatedCounter==1){
        System.out.println("There's an isolated vertex");
    }
    else
        System.out.println("There's no isolated vertex");
    //end of isolated check
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
}
```

}

I hope I'm not breaking any rule by posting this, if I did please tell me.

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: You're not "breaking rules", but you are posting a bad question. It's far too long. Read [ask]. Create a MCVE.

Comment: I'm really sorry that it's too long, but as I said, I'm not familiar with reading input from text files, so I included the whole program to make it easier for people to help me.